What does 好まざるかぎり mean?

…確かに、人は「好まざるかぎり」相手の顔をよく覚えていない、

I've seen a character say this in a videogame.  I understand the sentence but "好まざるかぎり" what does it mean? I understand it's probably like "don't like"?

好まざる is the 連体形 (attributive form) of 好まず or 好まない in modern language.
'Indeed, if/as long as people don't like someone, they don't remember their face well.'
More natural in English perhaps as 'People only remember someone's face well if they like them.'
